# Why isn't wheel animating(moving from left side of screen to the right) Python 3 using zelle graphics

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, zelle-graphics

I am trying to animate the wheel drawn using the zelle graphics library. The wheel is not animating. What it is supposed to do is move from the left side of the screen to the right side. The function is inside the Wheel class. All it is is two circles which looks like a wheel. It doesn't rotate, the center is just supposed to make it move from one side to the next.

```
from graphics import *
class Wheel():

    def __init__(self, center, wheel_radius, tire_radius):
        self.tire_circle = Circle(center, tire_radius)
        self.wheel_circle = Circle(center, wheel_radius)

    def draw(self, win): 
        self.tire_circle.draw(win) 
        self.wheel_circle.draw(win) 

    def move(self, dx, dy): 
        self.tire_circle.move(dx, dy) 
        self.wheel_circle.move(dx, dy)

    def set_color(self, wheel_color, tire_color):
        self.tire_circle.setFill(tire_color) 
        self.wheel_circle.setFill(wheel_color)

    def undraw(self): 
        self.tire_circle .undraw() 
        self.wheel_circle .undraw() 

    def get_size(self):
        return self.tire_circle.getRadius()

    def get_center(self):
        return self.tire_circle.getCenter()

    def animate(self, win, dx, dy, n):
        if n > 0:
            self.move(dx, dy)
            win.after(100, self.animate, win, dx, dy, n-1)


# Define a main function; if you want to display graphics, run main()
# after you load code into your interpreter
def main():
    # create a window with width = 700 and height = 500
    new_win = GraphWin('Wheel', 700, 500) 

    # What we'll need for the wheel...
    wheel_center = Point(200, 200) # The wheel center is a Point at (200, 
200)
    tire_radius = 100  # The radius of the outer tire is 100

    # Make a wheel object
    new_wheel = Wheel(wheel_center, 0.6*tire_radius, tire_radius)

    # Set its color
    new_wheel.set_color('red', 'black')
    # And finally, draw it 
    new_wheel.draw(new_win)
   # Run the window loop (must be the *last* line in your code)
    new_win.mainloop()
# Comment this call to main() when you import this code into
#  your car.py file - otherwise the Wheel will pop up when you
#  try to run your car code.

main()
```

Comment: you have to run `new_wheel.animate()` to start animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `animate()` to start animation

```
new_wheel.animate(new_win, 10, 0, 30)

new_win.mainloop()
```

Comment: That works, but could you explain the arguments within the function?

Comment: you don't know your code ? arguments `def animate(self, win, dx, dy, n):`

Comment: or more precisely `self=new_wheel`, `win=new_win`, `dx=10`, `dy=0`, `n=30`

Comment: Its not my code. This is a part project for school where i take that code and make the wheel move. I didnt write the all of that.

Comment: so now you see: in code you have definition `def animate(self, win, dx, dy, n)`, if you execute `new_wheel.animate(new_win, 10, 0, 30)` then you will have `self=new_wheel`, `win=new_win`, `dx=10`, `dy=0`, `n=30`